# INSERT Multiple with SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

i'm trying to use INSERT into with SELECT DISTINCT and this is what i tried so far.

```
INSERT INTO creature_loot_template VALUES (id, 68910, 0, 100, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, NULL)
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM creature WHERE map = 389;
```

So this is example of what it should do (there is more than 20 - 40 lines:

```
INSERT INTO creature_loot_template VALUES (123, 68910, 0, 100, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, NULL);
INSERT INTO creature_loot_template VALUES (124, 68910, 0, 100, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, NULL);
INSERT INTO creature_loot_template VALUES (125, 68910, 0, 100, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, NULL);
INSERT INTO creature_loot_template VALUES (125, 68910, 0, 100, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, NULL);
```

I've also tried the following SQL's :

```
INSERT INTO creature_loot_template VALUES ((SELECT DISTINCT id FROM creature WHERE map = 389), 68910, 0, 100, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, NULL);
```

```
SET
@id = (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM creature WHERE map = 389);
INSERT INTO creature_loot_template VALUES (@id, 68910, 0, 100, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, NULL);
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO creature_loot_template SELECT DISTINCT id, 68910, 0, 100, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, NULL FROM creature WHERE map = 389;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sql insert into table from select without duplicates (need more then a DISTINCT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916667/sql-insert-into-table-from-select-without-duplicates-need-more-then-a-distinct)

Comment: Yes that does help, i have saw already but i wasn't sure on how it should work but now i did so thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just list the values you want on the `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO creature_loot_template
    SELECT DISTINCT id, 68910, 0, 100, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, NULL
    FROM creature
    WHERE map = 389;
```

I would recommend that you list all the columns in the `INSERT` as well.  This ensures that the code does what you actually want.

Comment: I hope you didn't do the downvote, else your answer has solved my issue i'll accept whenever i can thank you

Comment: @JadaDeveloper . . . As someone who never downvotes, you can be assured that I did not downvote.  I find that comments are more useful.  And in cases where quality is really low, I just vote to close.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is probably redundant.

Comment: @RickJames . . . There is no indication in the question of whether there could be duplicates for a single `map`.  I do agree that it is *probably* redundant, but the OP has it in the question.  That comment should really be directed to the OP.